# jquery sliding div not working

Tags: sliding

I am trying to implement jquery code for my form to slide down
when clicked and slide up again when clicked again.

Here is my code:

```
 $("document").ready(function(){
    $("#login").click(function()
    {
$("#login").bind("click",fnclick);
   });

function fnclick(evt){
    ("#form").toggle(clicked,unclicked);

}
function clicked(){
    $("#form").animate({height:"90px"},1000)
}
function unclicked(){
    $("#form").animate({height:"0px"},1000)
}

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just create two classes (one for it to be positioned "slid up" and one for "slid down") and use .toggleClass

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#elementToBeClicked").click(function(){
$("#elementToBeClicked").toggleClass("slidUpClass").toggleClass("slidDownClass")
});
```

Answer (score 0):

well i don't understand what is your problem, is it that click function isn't working or slideing animation is broken...

if it's animation problem use jquery functions to slide elements:

```
$("#form").slideUp();
$("#form").slideDown();
```

Here is a simple demostration: http://jsfiddle.net/isair/mfmU7/4/

and i just realised that one of your selector is mising $, its probably just a typo